# How many projectiles from a single attack can you catch with Snatch Arrows?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

Certain ranged attacks involve shooting multiple projectiles at once, but it's still a single attack. So what if you are shot by, say, Manyshot, or that one monster from the ELH who can throw 50 boulders as a single attack (discounting the fact that "unusually massive" attacks can't be caught this way: imagine being Enlarged in this particular case), can you catch all the projectiles? Snatch Arrows is derived from Deflect Arrows, which reads:

> Once per round when you would normally be hit with a ranged weapon, you may deflect it so that you take no damage from it.

So are you stuck with catching just one projectile, or can you end up with a fist full of arrows?

Comment: Technically, by the strictest reading you can't deflect any projectiles with Deflect Arrows, only ranged weaponry, but it provides a good defence against pistol whips.

Comment: I like the imagery of a Rogue staring up at a volley of 50 Boulders and dropping his dagger to have a free hand, though.

Comment: @Axoren The rogue, of course, must take a free action to drop his dagger (if he's dual-wielding) *on his turn before the attack is launched* so he even *has* that free hand. Damn, the feat Deflect Arrows hurts. Seriously, what is the balance concern over batting away an arrow once per round while one's hands are full? If it's only imagery, how about just cutting the arrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unknown.

Most Volley attacks, including the [Manyshot feat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#manyshot) specify that the 'arrows', 'spines', or 'small thrown weapons' (Palm Shot), use 'the same attack roll' and 'only apply precision damage once'.  This *seems* to indicate a single attack, which is therefore a single *hit*, and is therefore deflected entirely by Deflect Arrows.  However, it doesn't say this.  It also doesn't specify that 'firing two arrows' means 'two attacks'.  It's undefined, and I can't find anything answering this question in the FAQ, so even that crappy source doesn't resolve it.

In some cases I believe they instead use 'single attack which adds the base damage of the arrow multiple blah times' wording, in which case *yes*, deflect arrows would indeed deflect the entire attack.

But as for Manyshot, that comes down to a GM call.  I'd allow it, because Deflect Arrows isn't the greatest feat in the world.  And if you have it, you're probably a monk, and god knows they need the help.  I'd allow Snatch Arrows to hurl back the entire Manyshot as well, just because again, it's a sub-par feat and the coolness factor is high.

Comment: +1 for "I allow it because it is cool", which is the way everyone should DM. And if you play a Monk as a wuxia hero, it would not be too far-fetched.